# How do you access the response headers in a Starlette app?

Tags: python, starlette

Is there a way to access the headers that will be included in the response without writing a custom middleware to intercept them?  For example, how would I get the expiration date/time of a cookie set by the SessionMiddleware, or its last access?  I haven't been able to find any documentation suggesting this is possible, only how to manually set and delete cookies in a Response.